# What are some tips for someone transitioning to SharePoint 2010 from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I have mostly worked with ASP.NET WebForms and more recently MVC.  I am now starting the long journey of moving over to SharePoint 2010 development and would love to learn from your experiences.

I ran across a great article last night for people like me making the move: http://reddevnews.com/articles/2011/02/01/making-the-sharepoint-transition.aspx.  I think one of the best tips I read is not to think of SharePoint in terms of pages, but resources.  If you're plugging in static web pages, rather than reusable webparts, you're not doing it the "SharePoint way".

What advice/tips do you have for the developer transitioning from the ASP.NET Web Application world to SharePoint Development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Brush up on your WebForms knowledge, your MVC skills probably won't matter much
- Learn the CAML schema like the back of your hand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx
- Put in requests for x64 hardware sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to start with videos at Microsoft SharePoint Developer Center http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905692

It was my start point :)